# Clojure Hot Reload

Tags: docker, clojure, docker-compose, dockerfile, clojurescript

what is the best option to run Clojure in development with docker-compose and Hot Reload?
I am investigating about Clojure repl and trying to run inside Docker container but unsuccessful.

Currently we are running Clojure app without Docker and on every change we manually restart Clojure App.

I am also tried inotify-tools, watching clojure directory for changes but when i run Docker container i have following error "Please install rlwrap for command editing or use "clojure" instead." and container is stopped.

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM clojure:openjdk-11-tools-deps

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    inotify-tools 

COPY deps.edn .

RUN clojure -e "(clojure-version)"

COPY ./src /usr/src/app/src

COPY ./data /usr/src/app/data

COPY .lein-env .

RUN  cd /usr/src/app/data/questions && ls -la

RUN ls -la


COPY test test/
COPY test.sh .
COPY watch.sh .
COPY run.sh .

EXPOSE 8800 8888

#CMD ["clojure", "-m", "bloom.server.core"]
# Run CLojure Service
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./watch.sh"]
```

Watch script

```
    #!/bin/bash

# Inotify script to trigger a command on file changes.
#
# The script triggers the command as soon as a file event occurs. Events
# occurring during command execution are aggregated and trigger a single command
# execution only.
#
# Usage example: Trigger rsync for synchronizing file changes.
# ./watch.sh rsync -Cra --out-format='[%t]--%n' --delete SOURCE TARGET


######### Configuration #########

EVENTS="CREATE,CLOSE_WRITE,DELETE,MODIFY,MOVED_FROM,MOVED_TO"
COMMAND="$@"
WATCHDIR=/src

## Exclude Git and temporary files from PHPstorm from watching.
EXCLUDE='(\.git|___jb_|sites/default/dev)'

## Whether to enable verbosity. If enabled, change events are output.
VERBOSE=0

##################################

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
 echo "Usage: $0 Command"
 exit 1;
fi

##
## Setup pipes. For usage with read we need to assign them to file descriptors.
##
RUN=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo "$RUN"
exec 3<>$RUN

RESULT=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo "$RESULT"
exec 4<>$RESULT

clean_up () {
  ## Cleanup pipes.
  rm $RUN
  rm $RESULT
}

## Execute "clean_up" on exit.
trap "clean_up" EXIT


##
## Run inotifywait in a loop that is not blocked on command execution and ignore
## irrelevant events.
##
inotifywait -m -q -r -e $EVENTS --exclude $EXCLUDE --format '%w%f' $WATCHDIR | \
  while read FILE
  do
    if [ $VERBOSE -ne 0 ]; then
      echo [CHANGE] $FILE
    fi

    ## Clear $PID if the last command has finished.
    if [ ! -z "$PID" ] && ( ! ps -p $PID > /dev/null ); then
      PID=""
    fi

    ## If no command is being executed, execute one.
    ## Else, wait for the command to finish and then execute again.
    if [ -z "$PID" ]; then
      ## Execute the following as background process.
      ## It runs the command once and repeats if we tell him so.
      ($COMMAND; while read -t0.001 -u3 LINE; do
        echo running >&4
        $COMMAND
      done)&

      PID=$!
      WAITING=0
    else
      ## If a previous waiting command has been executed, reset the variable.
      if [ $WAITING -eq 1 ] && read -t0.001 -u4; then
        WAITING=0
      fi

      ## Tell the subprocess to execute the command again if it is not waiting
      ## for repeated execution already.
      if [ $WAITING -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "run" >&3
        WAITING=1
      fi

      ## If we are already waiting, there is nothing todo.
    fi
done
```

system.clj

```
(ns testapp.server.system
  (:require
   [com.stuartsierra.component :as component]
   [testapp.server.internal.service :as internal-service]
   [testapp.server.internal.rest :as internal-rest]
   [testapp.server.internal.html :as internal-html]
   [testapp.server.app.service :as app-service]
   [testapp.server.app.rest :as app-rest]
   [testapp.server.settings :as settings]))

(defn new-system []
  (merge (component/system-map)
         (settings/new-settings-provider)
         (internal-service/new-server)
         (internal-rest/new-provider)
         (internal-html/new-provider)
         (app-service/new-server)
         (app-rest/new-provider)
         ))
```

core.clj

```
(ns testapp.server.core
  (:require
   [com.stuartsierra.component :as component]
   [testapp.server.system :as system])
  (:gen-class))

(defonce server (atom nil))

(defn stop-server []
  (component/stop-system @server)
  (reset! server nil))

(defn start-server [system]
  (reset! server (component/start-system system)))

(defn -main [& args]
  (start-server (system/new-system))
  (if @server
    (println (str "Services started on the following ports:\n"
                  "\n- Internal API: "
                  (get-in @server [:settings-provider :settings :internal-api-port])
                  "\n- App API: "
                  (get-in @server [:settings-provider :settings :app-api-port])
                  "\nAll running in the "
                  (get-in @server [:settings-provider :settings :run-env])
                  " environment."
                  ))
    (println "Starting the server failed somehow ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯")))
```

settings.clj

```
    (ns testapp.server.settings
  (:require
   [com.stuartsierra.component :as component]
   [environ.core :refer [env]]))

(defrecord Settings [settings]
  component/Lifecycle
  (start [this]
    (assoc this :settings
           {

            :internal-api-port
            (or (some->> (env :internal-api-port) str (re-matches #"\d+") Integer.)
                8800)

            :app-api-port
            (or (some->> (env :app-api-port) str (re-matches #"\d+") Integer.)
                8888)

            :run-env
            (or (some #{(env :run-env)} ["local" "dev" "staging" "production"])
                "local")

            :google-auth-client-id (env :google-auth-client-id)
            :google-auth-client-secret (env :google-auth-client-secret)
            :google-auth-callback-host (env :google-auth-callback-host)



            }))
  (stop [this] (assoc this :settings nil)))

(defn new-settings-provider []
  {:settings-provider (map->Settings {})})
```

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe add some examples about your workflow?  Also, I'm not sure how docker-compose is involved.

Comment: Hi @AlanThompson. I updated my post. Can you please check it. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: As the error message states: you are running most likely `clj` somewhere (which is just a call to `rlwrap clojure "$@"` basically.  Either install rlwarp inside your container or use `clojure` directly.

Comment: Thank you @cfrick. I am going to try. How you use clojure in local development. What is your way to have hot reload ?

Comment: Also why not go the "clojurey" route and use a "reload" workflow?  E.g. in your case  https://github.com/stuartsierra/component#reloading make sense

Comment: I always use a REPL.  I either do reloading forms or namespaces or use a full blown reload workflow with tools.namepace.

Comment: If your Clojure code compiles to class files, maybe you can try DCEVM (Dynamic Code Evolution VM). I use it for mixed Clojure/Java projects to hotswap freshly compiled Java code without restarting the REPL. Here is an example: https://github.com/jonasseglare/hotswap-dcevm-clojure-demo

Comment: To solve the command `rlwrap` being missing, you can add the [rlwrap](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/rlwrap) package in your Dockerfile in the line where you run `apt-get install ...`

Answer (score 0):

In the REPL you can reuse the code from [duct](https://github.com/duct-framework/core/blob/3dc4908902cff81323bee89eaef94012194cbd24/src/duct/core/repl.clj#L31) framework. It will need only [hawk](https://github.com/wkf/hawk) file watcher as a dependency in a dev environment.

Here is how it can be looks like:

```
(defn- clojure-file? [_ {:keys [file]}]
  (re-matches #"[^.].*(\.clj|\.edn)$" (.getName file)))

(defn- auto-reset-handler [ctx event]
  (binding [*ns* *ns*]
    (clojure.tools.namespace.repl/refresh :after 'function.to.restart.system/restart)
    ctx))

(defn auto-reset
  "Automatically reset the system when a Clojure or edn file is changed in
  `src` or `resources`."
  []
  (hawk.core/watch! [{:paths ["src/"]
                      :filter clojure-file?
                      :handler auto-reset-handler}]))
```